# Distribute windows MAUI application through web

Tags: azure, maui, maui-windows, appinstaller, windows-application-packaging

**I am working on the MAUI windows application. I want to distribute the application via the web (not via the app store). The user should get a notification about the update on the application launch whenever we update something in the application.** I have gone through various articles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162637/how-to-configure-auto-update-in-maui-application
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/create-appinstallerfile-vs

**The steps which I have followed**

- I created a sample MAUI application.
- I made a web application with 1 HTML page. I also made necessary changes to the web.config file to allow the webserver to serve resources with the appropriate file extension like .msix (mimeMap settings).
- In the HTML page, put the app installer link inside the anchor tag. (we can also use a normal anchor tag but the msix file can not install directly, first, we need to download it first and then install it.
- Host the site on local IIS.
- Then, I created a self-signed certificate, make publish profile, whatever steps are required to make the App package of the MAUI app. During the process, I also configured update settings where I need to give the Installer location. So, I gave my web application URL http://localhost/AppDistribution/Files/
- I successfully created an App Package, I manually put the .msix file in the “Files” folder of the web application. (The same path is given in the anchor tag).
- Now whenever I click on the anchor tag link, I can directly install the application, and if the application is already installed then the system asks to update the application.
- ***Question - The same thing I want to do on application launch, whenever we launch the application, the system checks whether any new package is uploaded on the given web application link if yes then it directly notifies me to update the application.***

It is working on WPF application. I upload the updated application bundle in the http://localhost/AppDistribution/Files/ and when I launch the application, I get the notification about the application update. **Why the same approach is not working in the MAUI windows application?**

**Is it because instead of uploading only msix file, I should upload the entire application bundle? or the issue occurs because I am using a self-signed certificate, not a distribution one.**

Comment: please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: For auto-updates maybe see this: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7161  (apparently it doesn't notify you that it is updating and updates don't appear until restarting?)

Comment: I updated the description. I got the answer to a few questions but still have some doubts.